# Trying to generate a random graph, and then generate another one until it is isomorphic with the first one

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, graph, networkx, isomorphic

I am new to python and am trying to write a program that can take a matrix of 1's and 0's as an input, create a graph from it, then keep generating another random graph until it find an isomorphic pair.

I keep messing up my logic and keep getting either an infinite loop or a loop that doesn't accomplish what I want accomplished. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the part of my program with the issue

```
i = 0
for i in range(counterP):
    g4 = numpy.reshape(numpy.random.random_integers(0, 1, size=matrix_sizeP), (vertex_countP, vertex_countP))
    g5 = numpy.reshape(numpy.random.random_integers(0, 1, size=matrix_sizeP), (vertex_countP, vertex_countP))
    G4 = nx.Graph(g4)
    G5 = nx.Graph(g5)
    G4G5 = iso.GraphMatcher(G4,G5)
    isomP = G4G5.is_isomorphic()

    if isomP is True:
        ed = nx.number_of_edges(G4)
        print("Iteration", i, ":", ed, "edges")
        print(G4G5.mapping)
        i = i + 1
    else:
        g5 = numpy.reshape(numpy.random.random_integers(0, 1, size=matrix_sizeP), (vertex_countP, vertex_countP))
        G5 = nx.Graph(g5)
        isomP = G4G5.is_isomorphic()
```

Comment: Why are you doing that? It seems like an extremely inefficient way to solve any problem I can imagine this being a solution attempt for.

Comment: The end result would be a random isomorphic graph.  It's much, much, much easier just to generate a random isomorphic graph by randomly permuting the vertices.

Comment: Do you have any links to a good source for that? New to all of this

Comment: I'm assisting professors at my university with Graph Theory research and this is the task they assigned me

Comment: Maybe they are ultimately interested in the graphmatcher and the loop they asked you to write is meant as a testing framework?

Comment: At the very least, I would recommend starting with a 2x2 matrix

Answer (score 1):

Your program logic is indeed slightly off. Here is a version which does what I understand you want:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.isomorphism import GraphMatcher

def brute_force_find_iso_pair(shape, maxiter, template=None):
    def make_random_graph():
        return nx.Graph(np.random.random_integers(0, 1, shape))
    G4 = make_random_graph() if template is None else template
    def check_iso(G5):
        return GraphMatcher(G4, G5).is_isomorphic()
    for n in range(maxiter):
        G5 = make_random_graph()
        if check_iso(G5):
            break
    else:
        G5 = None
    return G4, G5, n + 1

# example
G4, G5, n = brute_force_find_iso_pair((4, 4), 50)
print(f"""After {n} iterations:
template: {G4.adj}
match:    {G5 and G5.adj}
""")
```

Sample runs:

```
After 43 iterations:
template: {0: {1: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}}, 1: {0: {'weight': 1}, 1: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 2: {1: {'weight': 1}, 0: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 3: {0: {'weight': 1}, 1: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}}}
match:    {0: {2: {'weight': 1}, 1: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 1: {0: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}}, 2: {0: {'weight': 1}, 1: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 3: {1: {'weight': 1}, 0: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}}

After 50 iterations:
template: {0: {1: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}}, 1: {0: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}}, 2: {0: {'weight': 1}, 1: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 3: {1: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}}}
match:    None

After 25 iterations:
template: {0: {1: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}}, 1: {0: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}}, 2: {1: {'weight': 1}, 0: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}}, 3: {0: {'weight': 1}}}
match:    {0: {1: {'weight': 1}}, 1: {0: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 2: {1: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 3: {1: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}}}

After 2 iterations:
template: {0: {0: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 1: {2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 2: {0: {'weight': 1}, 1: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 3: {0: {'weight': 1}, 1: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}}}
match:    {0: {2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 1: {1: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 2: {0: {'weight': 1}, 1: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 3: {0: {'weight': 1}, 1: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}}

After 32 iterations:
template: {0: {2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 1: {2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 2: {1: {'weight': 1}, 0: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 3: {1: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}, 0: {'weight': 1}}}
match:    {0: {1: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 1: {0: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}}, 2: {0: {'weight': 1}, 1: {'weight': 1}, 3: {'weight': 1}}, 3: {0: {'weight': 1}, 2: {'weight': 1}}}
```

Comment: Wow this is really great, this is exactly the type of thing I was looking for, and in doing so you also taught me a bit about how defining functions in python works, and also a little more about the logic behind these loops.

Really, thank you for this, its deeply appreciated!

Comment: would you mind explaining the output? I'm assuming its a mapping, I'm just having trouble following it exactly. Thanks

Comment: @Jrubinstein Yes, it's a nested dictionary-like mapping, representing the graph. Each vertex is mapped to a mapping from each of its neighbors to a mapping from the connecting edge's properties to their values. See [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.adj.html)